# unlink not working when getting a url from loadHTML

Tags: php, unlink

I have a weird issue. I have a script that I run which will loop through a table that has some records in it containing HTML. In that html are images that I need to delete when the script is ran. Here is how I am doing it

```
while ($row_find = $result_find->fetch_array()) {
    $comment = $row_find['comment']; <--this is html
    $html = $comment;
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    // images
    foreach ($imgs as $img) {
        $src = stripslashes(trim($img->getAttribute('src')));
        $img_new = str_replace("https://www.example.com","/home/document/path/html/root",$src);
        unlink($img_new);
    }           
}
```

What I am doing is loading the html through `loadHTML` and then using `$doc->getElementsByTagName('img')` to get the `attr` `src` of the image. Then change the path of that image to the document root and then simply `unlink($img_new)`

Problem is this is not working. I have checked the path a million times and it is correct, the permissions on the folder and file are correct. I have used `trim` to make sure there is no white space ,but in this script is does not work

Now if I take the same `unlink('/home/document/path/html/root/thisimage.png')` except I write in the path manually and place it at the top of the script it works fine and the image is removed.

The path is correct, but it will not delete. Is this something to do with creating the image path from a `DOMDocument`?

Comment: Can you show what you get when you do `var_dump($img_new)`, right before `unlink()`?

Comment: I am some what uncomfortable with the foreach loop in there because $imgs is not an array. Foreach loop works only on arrays. I feel that you just have to unlink after $imgs without the foreach loop

Comment: @brad that worked lol. I did a var dump and there was double quotes in the string src path so it was looking like `""/home/document/path/html/root/thisimage.png"".` I did a `string_replace` to remove the first set of quotes and it worked. Make it an answer and I can vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run into stuff like this, I always use `var_dump()` to see for sure what's in the variable.  Sometimes things get missed with just `echo()`.

Looks like in this case, it was an extra set of quotes.  Glad you found it!